# Single and double quotes in the same bash input

Tags: bash, character-encoding

I want to give input to a bash read function which contains both single and double quotes at the same time, then have it compare with a stored value.

This script asks a random question on startup, looking for correct syntax of some commands I want to memorize. However some of these commands contain both single and double quotes, so how to handle this with bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is the secret string?"
read secret

if [ "$secret" = "123" ]
then
  echo "You're Awesome!!!"
else
  echo "You're memory sucks!!"
fi
```

So if $question is "Hi my name is 'Ed'" including the single AND double quotes in the same input, how do I work this magic?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `read` would read the characters you typed, just as you typed them (apart from some characters preceded by backslash unless you use `read -r`).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do / what problem you're having. Your last sentence -- the actual question part -- mentions the variable `$question`, but that variable doesn't appear in the code you've posted. Can you update your code to match your actual use-case?

Comment: (To add to my previous comment: try posting code that *doesn't* work, together with an explanation of what it's trying to do. We can then help you fix that code.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic to be worked. The input from the user never becomes *syntax* within your script — it is never evaluated as code — so it can contain *anything.**

* Except for the NUL character (\0) itself, since that is the string terminator character.

Answer (score 0):

`read`ing strings that contain quotes doesn't require anything special, but I'd use `read -r` to prevent it messing with backslashes. You can also use the `-p` option to supply a prompt (instead of `echo`ing it separately):

```
read -r -p "What is the secret string? " secret
```

The only tricky thing here is specifying the string to compare with. One option is to express it as a double-quoted string, and escape the double-quote(s) within it with backslashes. You'll also need to escape any dollar signs, backticks, or backslashes the same way:

```
if [ "$secret" = "dq: \", sq: ', dollar: \$" ]
then
        echo "You're Awesome!!!"
else
        echo "Your memory sucks!!"
fi
```

Here's an example run of the above code:

```
$ ./secrettest.sh
What is the secret string? dq: ", sq: ', dollar: $
You're Awesome!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

My question was about specifying the string in the code as Gordon mentioned, not reading it from the input. I had escaped the double quotes and single quotes in my original which is why it didnt work.
So this

```
if [ "$secret" = "command \'with \"options\"\'" ]
```

Should have been this

```
if [ "$secret" = "command 'with \"options\"'" ]
```

Thanks guys.